# Adding two fragments in activity, one containing Scroll able listview and another containing static content

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add two fragments in activity, one containing Scroll able listview and another containing static content.
I want to achieve view something like :

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What, **specifically**, is your question?

Comment: My question is, how to pragmatically achieve this layout using fragments as one view is scroll able and other is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1: `LinearLayout`

(partial layout code follows)

```
<LinearLayout>
  <fragment android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
  <fragment android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Option #2: `RelativeLayout`

(partial layout code follows)

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <fragment
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom" />
  <fragment
    android:id="@id/bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am sure that there are other options, but those are two classic solutions.